# Comparison of Fingerprints of Discrete Distributions

Tags: distributions, distance

Let us assume that we are given $m$ iid samples from an unknown discrete distribution over $[k]$. Let's also assume that we are interested in a distributional property that is label-invariant. Let us define the fingerprint $f$ (also known as collision statistics or histogram of histogram) of the $m$ samples as a vector whose $i$th coordinate equals the number of elements which appear exactly $i$ times in the sample. As an example, $f[1]$, the number of elements which appears exactly once in the sample is likely to be maximized for the uniform distribution. Uniformity is one example of a label-invariant distribution property that remains invariant under relabeling of elements. Entropy and support size are other properties of distributions that also remain invariant under element relabeling.

The question that I am interested in is the following: Let $P$ and $Q$ be two discrete distributions having total variation distance at most $\epsilon$, for some small $\epsilon>0$. What can we say about the fingerprints of the samples of size $m$ of these two distributions? How close the respective fingerprints would be? What would be an appropriate notion of distance between the fingerprints?

Thanks,

Comment: It's hard to conceive of any "label-invariant distributional property" of any such distribution unless it is uniform, because (a) the support is not allowed to vary and (b) if by "label-invariant" you mean invariant under permutations of the support, then it appears that to have any non-trivial invariant properties, the probabilities must be constant on each orbit and uniformity immediately follows. Could you provide a non-trivial example of what you mean?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Entropy of a distribution, support size of a distribution are other examples of label-invariant distribution properties. Edited the question.

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by "label-invariant" then?  My guess is that "$[k]$" is your set of labels and that by "label-invariant" you allow for bijections between this set and any other set, rather than bijections between this set and itself (which is what you currently write), but it would be nice to know for sure.  There is a *unique* entropy in the latter case--that of the uniform distribution.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion over the terminology, I am using terms in CS literature.  "A property D of distributions (over [k]) is label invariant if for every distribution X in D and for every permutation π : [k] → [k], the distribution π(X) is in D". Paraphrased the definition from this book (Section 11.1.3, Page 299) (https://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~oded/PDF/pt-v3.pdf).

Comment: Thank  you.  The important fact is that by "distribution" you mean *family* of distributions!  That means your question has many possible different answers depending on what that family might be.  For instance, one way to produce a label-invariant family is to take an arbitrary set of distributions and include all their permuted versions.  The answers depend on which set of distributions you begin with.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Consider the following example. Suppose we have sample access to two distributions, one of them uniform over [k] and the other distribution over [k] with coordinate values either (1+\eps)/k or (1-\eps)/k for some small \eps>0, and it is a distribution. We obtain m iid samples independently from each of the two distributions and compare their fingerprints. How close would the fingerprints be?

Comment: I believe it might help your question attract useful answers if you were to include those specifics in it directly.